# Update listview items, that live in a AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview, adapter, edit, android-alertdialog

I build an AlertDialog in a class that extends DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    Intent locationTypesIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocationTypesRetrieverService.class);
    getActivity().getApplicationContext().startService(locationTypesIntent);

    itemsOnList = new CharSequence[noOfItems];
    itemsChecked = new boolean[noOfItems];
    for(int i=0;i<noOfItems;i++)
    {
        itemsOnList[i] = "Location " + i;
        itemsChecked[i] = true;
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Filter locations")
           .setMultiChoiceItems(itemsOnList, itemsChecked, 
                   new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                        System.out.println("clicked choice");                           
                    }
                }
     );
    createdAlertDialog = builder.create();
    return createdAlertDialog;
}
```

I then attempt to retrieve the list in the AlertDialog, and change the Adapter, in order to update the displayed items:

```
public void updateOptions(String[] optionsArray)
{
    ListView list = createdAlertDialog.getListView();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),list.getId(),optionsArray);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    //list.invalidate();
}
```

I get an error:

E/AndroidRuntime(9401): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1020403 type #0x12 is not valid

What is going on???

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

under `onViewCreated` method of your fragment:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //...

    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sam.The trouble is i want to populate the list with some data retrieved from a server.How can i know the data is there when onViewCreated(...) is called?